# "year" as a Column Name in a MySQL Table

Tags: mysql

Is it okay to name a column in a MySQL table `year`? Any reason not to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can name it `year`, there is no reason not to do so because it is not the **[reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)** of mysql/sql.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sarfraz!
-Laxmidi

Comment: Please note that from version 5.5 YEAR is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 4):

If you [quote your identifiers properly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html), you can use almost any word you want:

```
SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [MySQL Keywords list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) if you're ever curious.

Comment: statenjason, thanks for the info. I'll use the list in the future. 

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 1):

Please note that from version 5.5 YEAR **is** a reserved keyword.

I also think that in this case statenjason's answer "Check the MySQL Keywords list if you're ever curious." should be the right one.

Answer (score 0):

It's not one of the [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html), so it should be fine.